# Is there a shorthand way to check for presence before assigning a variable in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.2, ruby-2.0

is there a shorter way to do this (considering `a` is already set to some value):

`a = b if b.present?`

I may have come across a way to do this before, but don't remember.

Answer (score 1):

Just `a = b if b.present?` on its own is functionally equivalent to:

```
if b.present?
  a = b
else
  a = nil
end
```

so you could use [`Object#presence`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-presence):

> **presence()**
>   Returns the receiver if it's present otherwise returns `nil`. `object.presence` is equivalent to
>
> ```
> object.present? ? object : nil
> ```

like this:

```
a = b.presence
```

If `a` already has a value and you're really saying:

```
a = something_interesting
a = b if b.present?
```

then you could say:

```
a = b.presence || something_interesting
```

Answer (score 1):

if b is some complex expression that you want to evaluate just once, you could use

`a = b.presence || a`

Answer (score 0):

you could do this

```
a = b if !b.nil?
```

or

```
a = b if b
```

or

```
a = b if b != nil
```

The thing about `present?` is it protects you against the trap of empty arrays, hashs, and other collections. So these will work if you are not concerned about an empty collection.

Comment: The last of those is emphatically _not_ the same as the others, or what the OP asked for. `a ||= b` is more akin to `a = b unless a` than `a = b if b`, which as a very different meaning.

Comment: Yup you are right, because there is no indication that this is an initial assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `||=` operator, but it depends on of what you want your code to do. This operator assigns the value of `b` to `a` if `b` is not `nil`.For example, if a = 5 and perform the following operation `a ||= b` value of `b` will be assigned to `a` **only if** `b` is not `nil`, but if `a` was not previously declared value of `a` will be `nil` for this code `a ||= b`.

EXAMPLES:

```
irb(main):001:0> b = nil
=> nil
irb(main):002:0> a ||= b
=> nil
irb(main):003:0> b = 5
=> 5
irb(main):004:0> a ||= b
=> 5
irb(main):005:0> a ||= nil
=> 5
```

Answer (score 0):

||= operator is what you are looking for. It checks if the operand is nil or present before assigning a value. If present doesn't assign, if nil or undefined will assign the value.

```
[1] pry(main)> a
NameError: undefined local variable or method `a' for main:Object
from (pry):1:in `__pry__'
[2] pry(main)> a ||= 100
=> 100
[3] pry(main)> a = nil
=> nil
[4] pry(main)> a ||= 100
=> 100
[5] pry(main)> a ||= 200
=> 100
```